# Get TreeView item text related to current item handling WM_NOTIFY / NM_CUSTOMDRAW?

Tags: winapi, comctl32

Subject says it all.  Is there a way when handling NM_CUSTOMDRAW for a tree view to get the text of the item currently being drawn?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you can get it using `dwItemSpec` in `NMCUSTOMDRAW` structure. See also `TVM_GETITEM` message.

Comment: Yes, I just found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-tree-view which documents the dwItemSpec.  It was a bit convoluted to find it.